# TriangularJS trouble with adding data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-material

Im using triangularjs and the action of adding a new item its not working properly because its not updating the table, and the description fields are coming as undefined

> Controller

```
function AddServiceTypeDialogController(ServiceTypeResource,$mdDialog, $http, currentType) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.post = currentType;

         ServiceTypeResource.getServiceTypes().then(function(response){

            vm.ServiceTypeList=response.data.response;
            console.log("ServiceTypeList",vm.ServiceTypeList);

         });



        vm.hide = function() {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        vm.cancel = function() {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
        };



        // vm.NewServiceType=[];
        vm.create = function() {

              vm.NewServiceType=[];
            var _service = {
                Description:vm.NewServiceType.Description,
                ProviderServiceTypeID:vm.ServiceTypeList.length + 1


            };
            console.log(_service);
            vm.ServiceTypeList.push(_service);
            clearModel();
            console.log("ServiceTypeList",vm.ServiceTypeList);




            // $http.post('http://138.197.195.46:3000/registerpartner', {
            //     account: '0xe99f7e5f1576dd2b535d2e8152be961138dfce10',
            //     name: vm.post.name,
            // }).then(function(r) {
            //     if (r.status != 200) return;
            //     var db = firebase.database().ref('partner');
            //     db.push(vm.post);
            //     vm.post = {};
                $mdDialog.hide();
            // });
        };
```

> And the form

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Add Partner" flex="60" flex-xs="90">
    <form ng-cloak ng-submit="vm.create()" novalidate>
        <md-dialog-content>
            <div class="md-dialog-content">
                <div layout="row" flex="100">

            </div>


                  <md-input-container>

  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.NewServiceType.Description" required md-maxlength="10">
</md-input-container>
        </md-dialog-content>
        <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
            <md-button ng-click="vm.cancel()">CANCEL</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-accent" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" type="submit">SAVE</md-button>
        </md-dialog-actions>
    </form>
</md-dialog>
```

This code its not updating the table

```
<tri-table class="packages-table" columns="vm.columns" contents="vm.ServiceTypeList" page-size="5"></tri-table>
```

and its sending Description as undefined